# All URLs are having '/blog/' appended to them.

Tags: permalinks

I just made a WP theme, and I'm using a custom page template for the blog and for the home.

The problem is that all the URLs now have /blog/ appended to them (which, I believe is the name of the page that's using the Blog Page Template).

Following an article in the Codex, I made the Blog page template empty, and instead added the blog content to `home.php`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Pages don't have a base in the URL unless you are associating the page with a parent in the "Page Attributes" section. Example:

Page 1 - "Contact Us" (no parent)

Page 2 - "Directions" (Contact Us as parent)

Page 1 URL - domain.com/contact-us

Page 2 URL - domain.com/contact-us/directions

Also, are you sure you're dealing with actual pages and not posts in a category?